# How to disable allow to delete prompt?

Tags: swift, iphone, swift4, ios13, swift5

I am trying to delete captured photos from my gallery using PHAsset like this:

```
    let assetIdentifiers = assets.map({ $0.localIdentifier })
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: assetIdentifiers, options: nil)
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assets)
    })
```

It works as I mentioned but I have a problem about system prompt are there any info.plist option or something to disable prompt.
Are there any way to close permission prompt?

( Allow *yourApp* to delete this photo )
[Prompt message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8teQL.png)

Comment: I feel like deleting a photo silently would be violating Apple's policies, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks for quick reply.